# The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:

Tags: apt, updates

please I need help.
I tried to install `osquery` on my Ubuntu and this is what I am getting:

```
Err:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Err:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu jammy InRelease    
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8CF63AD3F06FC659
Get:1 https://osquery-packages.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/deb deb InRelease [69.9 kB]
Err:8 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Err:11 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Err:12 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Err:1 https://osquery-packages.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/deb deb InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 97A80C63C9D8B80B
```

I have tried removing the keys but I keep getting this. I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$> gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C
```

And then

```
$> gpg --export --armor 871920D1991BC93C | sudo apt-key add - && sudo apt-get update
```

Repeat for each of your missing keys - you seem to have several.

Edit:

After version 22.04 apt-key is apparently deprecated

From the manpages

```
   If your existing use of apt-key add looks like this:

   wget -qO- https://myrepo.example/myrepo.asc | sudo apt-key add -

   Then you can directly replace this with the following (though note the recommendation
   below):

   wget -qO- https://myrepo.example/myrepo.asc | sudo tee
   /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/myrepo.asc
```

Comment: Note that traditional apt-key add functionality is considered 'deprecated' nowadays.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. After I entered the second command, this is what I got.

-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-14API:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# $> gpg --export --armor 871920D1991BC93C | sudo apt-key add - && sudo apt-get update 
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
$: command not found
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Comment: Following up on @ThomasWard comment. See the man page for apt-key here. I have updated my answer

Comment: Hey Nikolaj thank you for your post. Am just abit stuck. So where it says myrepo.example, do I put the repository name? For example I am trying to install osquery and this is how all these began,

Comment: The initial answer still works for me - you do get a warning message about deprecation. nikolaj@ThinkPad-X1:~$ uname -a
Linux ThinkPad-X1 6.2.0-26-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jul 10 23:39:54 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
nikolaj@ThinkPad-X1:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 23.04
Release: 23.04
Codename: lunar

Comment: @ThomasWard  Not looking good at all for me.
Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_pkg_osquery_io_deb-jammy.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/osquery.list:1

Comment: So remove one of them? Btw this is a seperate issue from the original post about missing public keys for your repository entries.

Comment: @Nikolaj what I meant was start the process all over by 
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/osquery.list
sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/osquery.asc
No still on the same topic. Forgive me if I seem a bit ignorant to this.